# Dissolving point files by shapefile boundaries

Tags: merge, attribute-joins, dissolve

I have a point-data file representing polling booth locations which each contain information pertaining to the vote for a political party that was recorded at each poll.

Underlying this file is a shapefile of SA2 areas (smaller statistical census areas).

I want to calculate an average of the polling results for all the polling locations contained within each SA2 and then merge this data into the attribute table of the SA2 shapefile. At the moment there are no common codes/ID numbers that I can aggregate them by.

[image]

Comment: Which GIS software are you using? Looks like ArcMap default symbology. Can you add a screenshot showing the point attrbute table?

Comment: How do you mean average? If Longreach, Ilfracombe and Isisford have very different population sizes,  you will be weighting smaller towns very heavily. I'd add them. You probably have a method.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem consists of three steps:

1. Get a common ID for the SA2 areas and the points.
2. Calculate your statistics
3. Merge the results back in the areas.

I am assuming you are using a recent version of QGIS. The following solution is certainly not elegant but simple and would not require you to write your own code in GIS.

**For 1:**
You can use `Join attributes by location` from your vector toolbox. It would create a new layer, in you case holding the point data with all their attributes and additional attributes from the polygon layer (e.g. ID or names).

**For 2:**
You can now calculate the statistics you like. I personally would not do this directly in GIS, since the standard functions here are a bit limited. You could certainly write some code to do this directly in GIS or use a virtual layer, but for a one time solution I would just export the new point layer into a CSV, open this in Excel or something and do your calculations there. In the end you should have one line for each SA2 area holding your averages etc. Each of this lines would represent one of the points, it does not matter which one.

**For 3:**
Reload the CSV into GIS as a vector layer and use the `Join attributes by location` tool again, only the other way around.